# Query manipulation database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, resultset

I am using some filters to display the products. Filters like colors, price and stuff.

Link : http://www.applechain.com/products/iPod.php

I use this query

```
$sql = "Select * 
  from tbl_product  
  where device='iPhone'  
    and (color='$c1'   
      or color='$c2'    
      or color='$c3'    
      or color='$c4'    
      or color='$c5'    
      or color='$c6'    
      or color='$c7'    
      or color='$c8'    
      or color='$c9'    
      or color='$c10'   
    ) and (storage='$cp1'    
      or storage='$cp2'    
      or storage='$cp3'    
      or storage='$cp4'    
      or storage='$cp5'   
    ) and (f_unlock='$factory')    
    and (warranty='$warranty')    
    and (price >= '$price1'    
      and price <= '$price2'   
    ) 
  order by product_id desc";
```

Now the thing is that I want to show the result even if all the queries are not satisfied. How about if just couple of options are matched and i want to display results on basis of that.

I'll appreciate help.

Comment: Then you want "or", not "and". Replace that and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT *       
        FROM tbl_product
        WHERE device = 'iPhone'
        AND color IN ('$c1', '$c2', '$c3', '$c4', '$c5', 
            '$c6', '$c7', '$c8', '$c9', '$c10') 
        AND storage IN ('$cp1', '$cp2', '$cp3', '$cp4', '$cp5') 
        AND f_unlock = '$factory'
        AND warranty = '$warranty'
        AND ((price >= '$price1') AND (price <= '$price2')) 
        order by product_id desc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this query:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        *, 
        1 as order_prority 
    FROM tbl_product
    WHERE 
        device = 'iPhone'
        AND color IN ('$c1', '$c2', '$c3', '$c4', '$c5', 
            '$c6', '$c7', '$c8', '$c9', '$c10') 
        AND storage IN ('$cp1', '$cp2', '$cp3', '$cp4', '$cp5') 
        AND f_unlock = '$factory'
        AND warranty = '$warranty'
        AND (price BETWEEN '$price1' AND '$price2') 
    UNION SELECT 
        *, 
        2
    FROM tbl_product
    WHERE 
        device = 'iPhone'
        AND (
            color IN ('$c1', '$c2', '$c3', '$c4', '$c5', 
                      '$c6', '$c7', '$c8', '$c9', '$c10') 
            OR storage IN ('$cp1', '$cp2', '$cp3', '$cp4', '$cp5') 
            OR f_unlock = '$factory'
            OR warranty = '$warranty'
            OR (price BETWEEN '$price1' AND '$price2') 
        )
    ORDER BY order_prority ASC, product_id DESC
";
```

In all cases you will receive some result. If first `SELECT` (more strict) returns something, the data will contain those results in the top, and second `SELECT` (more soft) will be in the end. If first `SELECT` will return nothing, you will having the data from the second, soft, query.